# Google Analytics, search URL has 18,000 pageviews with no search keyword

Tags: search, google-analytics, pageviews

The search page is showing up in Google Analytics where it never has before or as much that I would notice it in the top ten. The odd thing is that the search page has no keyword or phrase? I have been asked to figure out why this is happening, I can't really figure out where it is coming from. Link is below to generic search page

Search page from homepage after hitting GO without a value:

http://www.followthemoney.org/search-results/SearchForm?Search=Search&action_results=Go

I cannot recreate/figure out why the following URL is all of a sudden top ten pageviews in Google Analytics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clicking on the "Go" button to the top right seems to trigger that exact query. Maybe it's users not understanding how search works. If you want to prevent that, you could add a JavaScript check preventing submission of the form if there's nothing in the search field (or just the default "Search")... but given that the query produces meaningful results, you could just leave it

Comment: it adds in the "Search=Search" bit when you hit GO from the search bar. It is the default value. Are you saying they are basically the same pageview? Because one is SearchForm?action_results=Go and one is SearchForm?Search=Search&action_results=Go

Comment: Ah, no, apologies. That is a different thing, yeah. Weird

Comment: No worries thanks for the comment.

Comment: What are your site search settings in Google Analytics? In this particular view, do you have site search settings enabled, and strip query parameters enabled? This could be a reason for seeing search page views without the query part in it.

Comment: I updated my original question, added my site search settings. I do have the strip query parameters checked. If I uncheck that will it not track the keywords? Not really sure what is supposed to be checked or not on this part. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up unchecking the "category parameters out of URL" and "query parameters out of URL" option. I think I originally thought you had to check that or it would not save the users keyword that was entered into the search box. Glad I now know what that means...